# fitting specific formula/model in r - model possibly not identifiable

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, identifiability, nls

I would like to fit the following formula in R:

```r
y ~ alpha *(x1_0 * x2_0 * beta_0 + x1_1 * x2_1 * beta_1)
```

Here: `alpha`, `beta_0` and `beta_1` are parameters to be found. IVs are: `x1_0`, `x2_0`, `x1_1` and `x2_1` (there are actually more - `_n` indicates lag as it is more or less time series data).

My first thought is to use `nls` but I am also wondering if this formula/model is actually identifiable? Thanks!

Comment: You can factor out `beta_0`. There is no way to fit both `alpha` and `beta_0`.

Comment: @Roland - sorry I made a mistake in my formula. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\alpha  (x_{1,0} \, x_{2,0} \, \beta_0 + x_{1,1} \, x_{2,1}  \beta_1) = \alpha  \,x_{1,0} \, x_{2,0} \, \beta_0 + \alpha \, x_{1,1} \, x_{2,1} \, \beta_1
$$

rename $\gamma_0 = \alpha\beta_0$ and $\gamma_1 = \alpha\beta_1$ and this is

$$
\,x_{1,0} \, x_{2,0} \, \gamma_0 +  \, x_{1,1} \, x_{2,1} \, \gamma_1
$$

Now you can use linear regression with interaction terms. Notice that after estimating parameters of this model, you could pick *arbitrary* constant $\alpha$, and set $\gamma_0/\alpha = \beta_0$ and $\gamma_1/\alpha = \beta_1$, so this is not identifiable.

Comment: thanks. this makes sense. but I do not want to pick arbitrary values for alpha. I s my original formula identifiable? Also, IMHO the interpretation of parameters changes when including interactions so not sure if what you said makes sense in this context, where I also want to force the formula? Thanks!

Comment: @cs0815 what I'm trying to say that it is not. If you could use *any* value of $\alpha$ and this would work the same, then this shows that there's no "single best" value. This parameter only re-scales the other parameters, it does not interact with the data.

Comment: thanks. Let say I provide an estimate for each sample? Guess I could use an average given the data and then apply what you suggested?

Comment: @cs0815 I don't understand what you mean. I'm saying that this parameter is redundant, it does not play any role in the model.